# BSOD constantly with same ntoskrnl.exe error and disk indicator is frozen

Tags: windows-7, bsod, ntoskrnl.exe, machine-check-exception

BSOD constantly and the disk indicator is frozen.
Error do not happen immediately, usually an hour after boot up.

Here is the Minidump:
`Bug Check Code = 0x00000124`
`Caused By Driver = ntoskrnl.exe`
`Caused By Address = ntoskrnl.exe+4b094c`
`Crash Address = ntoskrnl.exe+4b094c`

Seems to be hardware problem, but I checked RAM, no error.
I have two HDs installed, system is on SSD, data is on HDD.
Checked SSD with the `properties->tools->error-checking` , no error.
Re-installed several times, still happens even after removed HDD.

Configuration:

- SSD: Crucial M4-CT064M4SSD2 with Firmware 0009
- Intel HM65
- CPU: i7-2630QM

The SSD is set correctly, SATA III 6Gb/s enabled, and everything worked perfectly for nearly a year.

I checked system events, it seems caused by an error from `WHEA-Logger`
`A fatal hardware error has occurred.

Reported by component: Processor Core

Error Source: Machine Check Exception

Error Type: Cache Hierarchy Error

Processor ID: 0

The details view of this entry contains further information.`

Cache Hierarchy Error, does this mean the CPU is broken?

Comment: you can check in system logs for disk errors; if there's any.  I saw this error also for sata controller related problems or memory corruption.  solved resetting CMOS (or changing the motherboard)

Comment: @Sheep: What model SSD do you have and have you checked if there is a firmware upgrade available for it? Can you check the BIOS at startup to see what mode the SATA controller is set to use? Information about the motherboard and other components would also be useful.

Comment: @James: I added the information you asked.

Comment: @Sheep: Have you tried Safe Mode? If the problem still occurs then I suspect there is a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about the SSD.
Crucial M4 with firmware 0009 has "5000 hour BSOD problem".
I updated the firmware, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/new-windows-7-64-machine-gets-bsod-help/17f42a05-880f-4f58-9b22-1ce6bd84ebd9

This has a lot of options - too many to copy into the body but the accepted answer was:

> AVG has been known to cause or aggravate these issues so I would
>   uninstall it and run the AVG Removal Tool to prevent trouble causing
>   remnants from being left behind. Below are recommendations to use
>   while testing, even better permanently.
>
> AVG Removal Tool - run this http://www.avg.com/us-en/utilities
>
> List of anti-malware program cleanup/uninstall tools
>   http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msestart/thread/407bf6da-c05d-4546-8788-0aa4c25a1f91/
>
> ---
>
> Here is what I use and recommend : (These are all Free versions and
>   very effective.)
>
> Avast and Prevx have proven extremely reliable and compatible with
>   everything I have thrown at them. Microsoft Security Essentials and
>   Prevx have also proven to be very reliable and compatible. Use MSE and
>   Prevx or Avast and Prevx however not all 3.
>
> Avast Home Free - stop any shields you do not need except leave
>   Standard, Web, and Network running.
>
> Prevx - Home - Free
>
> Windows Firewall
>
> Windows Defender (not needed if using MSE)
>
> IE - Protected Mode
>
> IE 8 - SmartScreen Filter ON  (IE 7 Phishing Filter)
>
> I also have IE to always start with InPrivate Filter active if IE 8.
>   (You occasionally have to turn it temporarily off with the little Icon
>   on LEFT of the + bottom right of IE)
>
> Two versions of Avast are available 6.x and 4.8x
>
> Avast 6.x - Home - Free - Stop the Shields you do not use (except
>   File, Web, Network, & Behavior) - double click the Orange Icon in
>   Notification Area - Real Time Shields - click the Shield you want to
>   stop - STOP. To stop the Orange Icon from showing an error indicator -
>   click the Orange Icon - Upper Right - Settings - click Status Bar -
>   uncheck the Shields you disabled - click OK
>   http://www.avast.com/free-antivirus-download
>
> Avast 4.8x - Home - Free - stop any shields you do not need except
>   leave Standard, Web, and Network running. (Double Click Blue icon -
>   details next to OK. - upper left Shields - Terminate those you do not
>   use.) http://www.avast.com/free-antivirus-download#tab4
>
> Or use Microsoft Security Essentials - Free
>   http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/
>
> Prevx works well along side Avast or MSE
>
> Prevx - Home - Free small, fast, exceptional CLOUD protection, works
>   with other security programs. This is a scanner only, VERY EFFECTIVE,
>   if it finds something come back here or use Google to see how to
>   remove.  http://www.prevx.com/   <-- information
>   http://info.prevx.com/downloadcsi.asp  <-- download
>
> PCmag - Prevx - Editor'a Choice
>   http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2346862,00.asp
>
> Also get Malwarebytes - free - use as scanner only. If you ever
>   suspect malware, and that would be unsual with Avast and Prevx running
>   except for an occasional low level cookie (no big deal), UPDATE it and
>   then run it as a scanner. I have many scanners and they never find
>   anything of note since I started using this setup.
>
> http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free

Answer (score 0):

Given the information provided, I can’t see any way to narrow down the cause of your BSOD sufficiently to hazard any guesses. The ntoskrnl.exe can be the apparent cause for many problems.

So… some generic advice:

According to the [Machine Check Exception (MCE) article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Exception) (the MCE is indicated by the stop code 0x00000124), common causes include:

Software:

- First thing to try is updating the drivers for your installed hardware. Make sure you include your Motherboard/Chipset drivers. If that doesn’t work, you might try updating your BIOS (just because).

Heat-related issues:

- Check to make sure the CPU heat-sync is securely attached, it might have shifted if the unit was moved or bumped.
- While you’re in there, make sure everything else (expansion cards, memory, whatever) is securely seated. Oh yeah, and clean out the dust bunnies.

Overloaded power supply:

- Have you added any power-hungry hardware? Any hardware at all? What about USB devices (those consume power too). Try removing all USB devices and see if the problem goes away.

If this issue has only recently manifested itself, try powering down your system and physical disconnecting any power sources for 30 seconds to 1 minutes before powering it back on. As silly as it sounds, and many people have told me I am silly, I usually start with this action because it resolves a surprise number of issues. I guess it's my equivalent of hitting the old TV set when it goes to snow.

If you can update your original post with an analysis of your dump file, that might help narrow down the problem.

To analyze a dump file:

[Download and install WinDbg from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).

[Download and install the Symbol Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028#_Installation_Instructions) appropriate for your system.

Open the dump file with the WinDbg program (file > open crash dump):

- A full dump file will (likely) be located here: %systemroot%\Memory.dmp
- A mini-dump (the default dump option of windows) will reside in the %systemroot%\Minidump folder

You don’t need to safe your workspace…

On the input line of the command window that appears when you open the crash dump, type:

```
!analyze –v
```

Press ‘Enter’

Update your original post with the output of this command (you can copy and paste from the WinDbg command window, but don’t include the information boxes surrounded by ‘*’ characters).

Good luck!

Comment: the system event says it's a "Cache Hierarchy Error", does this mean the cpu is broken?

Comment: @Sheep - Perhaps, but not necessarily. Something software could be corrupting the cache, or perhaps excessive heat is making those electrons jump around in unexpected ways. Have you tried the other generic troubleshooting suggestions (drivers, power, heat)? The fact that it takes about an hour for your issues to manifest makes me think in 'might' be heat related, but like I said, there's just not enough information yet to know for sure.

Comment: @Sheep - Have you been able to make any determinations about the cause of your crashing problems?